# Laravel - Getting user details for method used in both web and api routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

I have a project in Laravel where I am using the same method for both a web and api route. So for example i would have the following:

```
//routes/web.php 
Route::post("/import-results", "ImportController@doImport");

//routes/api.php
Route::post("/import-results/{auto}", "ImportController@doImport");
```

So regardless of the route the doImport() function will be called in the ImportContoller.

The import controller has a function like this (there is validation in the function but I have taken it out for simplicity):

```
public function doImport($auto = null){
   $importData = new DataImport();
   $importData->type = $_POST['type'];
   $importData->data = $_POST['data'];
   $importData->user = Auth::user()->name;
   $importData->save();

   $data = [
      "success" => true,
      "message" => "Message Here!"
   ]

   if($auto){
      return json_encode($data);
   }else{
      return view('import-message', $data);
   }
}
```

As you can see this method uses `Auth::user()->name;` to identify which user imported the data. This is fine if i am logging in and using a regular web route but what about if i'm using an API and using basic auth where no sessions are created and I don't want sessions to persist if the api routes are called.

How do i get the user info when calling API routes?

Also for the web routes i have customised my login as i'm using ldap but essentially the login happens by doing `$this->guard()->login($user, false);` in a class with the AuthenticatesUsers trait.

I could do this for my API routes too but does this creates a session and how do i clear this session once the request has ended? Or is there a better way??

Comment: you dont need sessions for auth .. there is token auth, it can still use the auth system

Comment: @lagbox i have updated my post to explain more. If i do `$this->guard()->login($user, false);` for the api route a session will be created. This is fine but it needs to kill that session at the end of the request. I'm not / don't want to use token auth for apis due to it being impossible to implement in the systems that are calling the API. Its using basic http auth.

Comment: which auth can already handle .... https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#stateless-http-basic-authentication

Comment: Why you need both api authentication and Web ? Use only one here Web. Php would work ?

Answer (score 0):

To make session work for both page submitting and api. You need work in web.php

Make both route in web.php

```
   //Web.php
   Route::post("/import-results", "ImportController@doImport");

   Route::post("/api/import-results/{auto}", "ImportController@doImport");
```

api.php is stateless mean no session exist in api.php . It's working with token based like JWT.

Comment: Maybe i have a fundamental misunderstanding about the way this should work but what i am trying to do is use ldap to authorise users using a login form and have api calls authorised by basic http auth but using the same methods that call Auth::user(); Is this possible?